# Workflow activity causing errors with type ViewStateNameValue

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-hosted-app, workflow-activity

I am using visual studio 2017 2017 with SharePoint online (a developer site) to create a SharePoint hosted app. I have just been using the workflow designer so haven't touched the XAML. When I click the start button, with workflow debugging on and a connection string to my azure service bus entered, it returns an error:

[image][image]

In the output panel it says microsoft.workflow.visualstudio.configurator.exe ended with an error.

If I then turn off workflow debugging and run it again this error does not happen (obviously) but if my workflow includes anything that gets the information of the Listitem or the workflow context it just gets rid of the step and replaces it with "Activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML":

[image]

It also returns errors for the "problem activity"

[image]

I even tried following a [blog post](https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/get-workflow-initiator-information-in-SharePoint-hosted-app.html) to the letter to see if I was missing a step but the same thing happens.

The really funny thing is that I have put this project on my home setup and the debugger runs fine! so I reset visual studio and replicated my home set up to ensure I haven't missed an important package somewhere but this is still happening!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was two errors:

- A reference was missing
- The microsoft.workflow.visualstudio.configurator.exe was trying to use the wrong credentials to authenticate me against the database